# Excel 2011 countif date range

Tags: excel, ms-office, countif

I am working on a project, and want to do the following:

I have a spreadsheet that has a datetime timestamp, a username (text string) and some other data irrelevant to me.

I want to count the number of rows in a date range and where the username equals a certain text string.

Please help! I have been looking at lots of message boards to try find the answers to this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula can help:

```
=COUNTIFS(K:K,"abc",J:J,">="&J2,J:J,"<="&J15)
```

Where K:K is the range where you have the usernames and "abc" is a sample name. And J:J is the timestamps range. J2 contains begin date and J15 contains end date for the required range.

Make sure date in J2 is lower than the date in J15 otherwise it will give 0 as answer

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for your reply!, I have tried this and it doe snot seem to be working and I am not sure why, The comparison dates are in cells on another sheet. I have uploaded what I have done to dropbox if you need a better idea of what im trying to do. The link is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6hhgo14evlrhxa/%21JOEY%21CancellationSaves%20Responses.xlsx thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: Because the date in first sheet is in another format than the date you trying to compare. Change NOW() function to today() and then try to match the values you will see the differences

Comment: change date in your first sheet to format: dd-mm-yyyy (its in mm-dd-yyy format now) and the formula should work. I changed a part of formula

Comment: Hey! I have the following formula in the sheet 'per Agent Calculations'!C2 =COUNTIFS('Form Responses'!G:G,"akealy@website.com",'Form Responses'!A:A,">="&'Team Details'!B13,'Form Responses'!A:A,"<"&'Team Details'!B12) the date format on ='Form Responses'!A:A is mm/dd/yyyy the same format as 'Team Details'!B12 to B16 is the same format mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: see the change i did in the formula in my post and try it

Comment: Hey! I have the following formula in the sheet 'per Agent Calculations'!C2 =COUNTIFS('Form Responses'!G:G,"akealy@website.com",'Form Responses'!A:A,">="&'Team Details'!B13,'Form Responses'!A:A,"<"&'Team Details'!B12) the date format on ='Form Responses'!A:A is mm/dd/yyyy the same format as 'Team Details'!B12 to B16 is the same format mm/dd/yyyy il re upload what i got to dropbox. link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6hhgo14evlrhxa/%21JOEY%21CancellationSaves%20Responses.xlsx sorry this did not fully post

Comment: sorry.... i have you now... change the format on the first sheet to mm/dd/yyyy and also do that for the sheet Team Details? I will try that now

Comment: That worked perfect, I didnt see you edited the original formula. Thanks so much for your guidence on this.